# Is there an updated version of servicestack swift plugin that works with Xcode7?

Tags: swift, servicestack, xcode7

The latest one is not working with Xcode7, can't even see the menu item in xcode. And also, my working project can't be built with Xcode7 now, JsonServiceClient.swift file causing a lot of build errors. Some are due to the error handling, others are dependency errors I didn't get a chance to read them fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for Swift 2.0 and Xcode 7 was added in ServiceStack v4.0.46, check out the [v4.0.46 Release Notes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2015/release-notes.md#v4046-release-notes) for more info.

You'll need to download the [ServiceStackXcode.dmg](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Swift/raw/master/dist/ServiceStackXcode.dmg) Xcode 7 plugin as well.

Comment: Fantastic! Exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

According to the auther of ServiceStack.Swift mythz wrote on 4 days ago:

> Xcode 7 with Swift 2.0 was only just released today, but will take some time to upgrade the library to support Swift 2.0. Check the release notes to see when Xcode 7 / Swift 2.0 is supported. https://forums.servicestack.net/t/servicestack-swift/1379

So I guess what we can do is waiting...

Comment: Working on it as we speak :) There's quite a few breaking changes in Swift 2.0 that we're getting through, but should be available within a couple of days if we don't hit any blockers! Keep an eye out for the next release on [@ServiceStack](https://twitter.com/ServiceStack) whether we're able to ship it or not.

Comment: I hope it's not going to be long or I'll have to fall back to use alamofire again.

Comment: @shawhu FYI we just [released Swift 2.0](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2015/release-notes.md#swift-20-support) in latest v4.0.46 release.